# CSS exclude cascade classes

Tags: javascript, css, cascading

Web Mind Help! I have html with many lists looks like

```
<li>A.</li>
<li><a href="#">B.</a></li>
<li><a class=tr href="#">C.</a></li>
<li class=tr>D.</li>
<li class=notr>E.</li>
```

I want select all untranslated innerText

```
document.querySelectorAll("li:not(.notr):not(.tr)")
```

Problem is if class TR not in LI i cannot filter it

`li:not(.notr):not(.tr)+li>a:not(.tr)` - returns empty NodeList

It seems to be a simple question but I'm confused

Comment: How it doesn't work? What element you need to target with the last selector?

Comment: Do you want all elements with no classname?.. since you try to exclude ".tr" and ".notr".?

Comment: By the way you are missing quotes for the class attributes.

Bad: <li><a class=tr href="#">C.</a></li> 
Good: <li><a class="tr" href="#">C.</a></li>

Comment: So you need only those texts that are not in a classed LI and also not in a classed A? (IOW only the first two from this example.) That can't be done with a singular querySelectorAll, so you'll need to do some filtering n the resulting collection.

Comment: Yee, im trying filtering result set but if text have TR words is skipped and it is slow

Comment: There may be a lot of such lists on the page and some may be with links, or just text

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in the comments, the solution is to fetch this collection first, then refine the results by running another filter over that.

```js
let rawresult = document.querySelectorAll("li:not(.notr):not(.tr)");

console.log('raw results:');
rawresult.forEach(el => console.log(el.innerText));

let refinedresult = [];
rawresult.forEach(function(el) {if (el.querySelector(".notr,.tr") == null) refinedresult.push(el);});

console.log('refined results:');
refinedresult.forEach(el => console.log(el.innerText));
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A.</li>
  <li><a href="#">B.</a></li>
  <li><a class=tr href="#">C.</a></li>
  <li class=tr>D.</li>
  <li class=notr>E.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes, that's a good answer, but not the best. If someone will give the answer with the filter in one line I will be grateful